# Como apresentar um listView com apenas uma linha com a cor alterada?

Tags: android

Pode parecer algo fácil mas estou apanhando. Eu precisava numa lista de 10 nomes, apresentar por exemplo o 3º nome na cor verde. Como eu faço para pegar a posição dele, não estou conseguindo, eu preciso apresentar esta lista com a cor modificada assim que abrir a tela. alguém pode dar um help? para alterar a cor de todos os componentes da lista eu apenas seto a cor de fundo da minha listView.

```
lv.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
```

Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá, Daniel. Uma sugestão é fazer um layout com os itens do seu ListView e associá-lo a um ListAdapter. Dá uma olhada no [Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29)

Exemplo:

```
         ArrayAdapter<String> meuAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>getApplicationContext(), 
                            android.R.layout.minha_lista_001, 
                            minhaLista) {

            @Override
            public View getView(int posicao, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                View view = super.getView(posicao, convertView, parent);
                TextView texto = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.texto1);

                if (posicao == 3 ) {
                    text.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                }else{

                //alguma coisa

    }  return view;
  }
};
```

Comment: Isso mesmo que eu precisava sparkss, vlw!!!!